# Spring OIDC – Getting Unable to convert claim 'iss' of type 'class java.lang.String' to URL.while parsing "iss" claim

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

I am having string value in iss but spring security is expecting iss value as URL.. Is it possible to change some bean to accept string value instead of URL.

Comment: Could you please provide a stacktrace?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert claim 'iss' of type 'class java.lang.String' to URL.
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClaimAccessor.getClaimAsURL(ClaimAccessor.java:122) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]

Comment: @Bean
    public JwtDecoderFactory<ClientRegistration> idTokenDecoderFactory() {
        OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory idTokenDecoderFactory = new OidcIdTokenDecoderFactory();
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer("string value");
        idTokenDecoderFactory.setJwtValidatorFactory(clientRegistration -> withIssuer);
        return idTokenDecoderFactory;
    }

i found some work around adding this bean and its started working.. I am not sure this is the proper way to move forward

Comment: Creating a `JwtDecoderFactory` bean is valid, since the issuer is known. Going back to the original problem, it appears the "iss" claim is not a valid URL. Do you know what the "iss" claim contains?

Comment: its just a string like "provider".. Its not a URL

Comment: Spring Security expects it to be a URL as per the spec. See the description of the ID token [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken).